# Database-JTable Interaction

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

Every time I implement a database viewer I have some functions that populate the table and adjust the column size. I would like to find ready component that can view the query result, also to sort, edit the entries in the table and automaticaly adjust the size of the column with respect to data. I want to use metadata to define the type of the entities automaticaly. The only thing that I will pass will be the ResultSet of the query and the component will do the rest. Any idea?

What I have done so far:

```
private static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}

public static void showResult(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
    //creates the table
    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
    table.setEnabled(false);

    //abjust table size
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);//the class for adjusting the column size
    tca.adjustColumns();    

    //JFrame
    JFrame view = new JFrame("View");
    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //add to frame
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    view.add(pane);

    //settings
    view.setVisible(true);
    view.setSize(table.getWidth(), 400);
}
```

And also I have a class that adjust the column size.

Answer (score 0):

```
To sort records use order by Clause to query you fire to get all records.
Use TableColumnModel to set column size.
Here is the code


//Your Edit Code
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from ManageVendor order by SName");
            table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
            TableColumnModel tcm=table.getColumnModel();
            tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
            tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
            tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tcm.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(60);
            tcm.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(50);
            tcm.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(250);
```